# Чего нельзя делать в конструкторе класса?

Tags: классы, c++

Всем привет!!!
Посмотрите, пожалуйста, нет ли ошибки, проверять долго, а гугл как-то внятного ответа давать не хочет. И нет ли у кого-нибудь ссылочки на мануалчик вроде "Чего нельзя делать в конструкторе класса!"=)

```
class WorksObject;

struct ThreadData {
    char qwerty[256];
    WorksObject* Obj;
};

class WorksObject {
public:
    WorksObject() : variable(false), ThHandle(NULL)
    {
        td = new ThreadData;

        strcpy(td->qwerty, "Text"); //Никакого Heap corruption не вылезет ?
        strcpy(qwerty1, "Text");    //Тут как ?
        td->Obj = this;             //Будет ли здесь нужный указатель ?
    }

    ~WorksObject()
    {
        if (ThHandle) CloseHandle(ThHandle);
        delete td;
    }

    void ФункцияВызываемаяПотом()
    {
        ThHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, WorkThread, td, 0, NULL);
    }

    static DWORD WINAPI WorkThread (LPVOID data)
    {
        ThreadData* ThData = (ThreadData*)data;
        if (ThData->Obj->variable)  //Вот в этом моменте c Obj все ок ???
        //...
    }

    HANDLE ThHandle;
    ThreadData* td;
    char qwerty1[256];
    bool variable;
}
```

p.s. В вопросах *памяти* дикие пробелы, исправлюсь в ближайшее время!:)

Спасибо!

Comment: Запутано как-то у Вас все. Если правильно понял, то для каждого потока Вы будете делать свой экземпляр WorksObject. Иначе (IMHO) потоки надо синхорнизировать (если несколько потоков будут работать с одним и тем же экземпляром), а никаких мьютексов или т.п. я не вижу.

Тогда td = new ... ни к чему. 

Вообще, WorkThread() у Вас член класса, поэтому он будет видеть все поля данного экземпляра. Следовательно ему и аргумент td (соответственно и ThData) не нужен. 

Передайте для проформы NULL и просто обращайтесь у переменным класса по именам `variable`, `qwerty`, `qwerty1`. Остальные не нужны.

Comment: 1. Я это написал для вопроса о конструкторах, а поток использовал для того что бы хоть какой то смысл был в присваивании указателя на себя из конструктора.
2. WorkThread он static, и из него до variable, qwerty и т.д. не достучишься.
3. А если не отдельный экземпляр ? Разве не только при записи синхронизировать надо ?

Comment: Да, static я не заметил. Кстати, зачем static ?

Пункт 3) не понял, что Вы имеете в виду (особенно "не только при записи синхронизировать" (а когда еще ?)).

Comment: static затем что вы в CreateThread функцию член класса не засуните(ну у меня не получалось еще) 
3-ий вопрос в том что в коде только чтение if (ThData->Obj->variable)

Comment: @lirik90, со static Вы правы. Нестатический метод вызвать не удастся, т.к. у него есть "скрытый" аргумент - this. Поэтому его сигнатура никак не совпадет с сигнатурой функции, которую требует CreateThread(,,WorkThread...).

Но, в WorkThread можно передать this и необходимость в td = new ThreadData (и вообще в структуре ThreadData) отпадает. Получается


    ...
       ThHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, WorkThread, this, 0, NULL);
    ...
    static DWORD WINAPI WorkThread (LPVOID data) {
        WorksObject *ths = (WorksObject *)data;
        if (ths->variable) // ну и к другим полям аналогично

Comment: 1. Повторюсь еще раз! Это просто набросок! И суть не в том как лучше, а в том будет ли это правильно работать, вы же два раза написали почти одно и тоже! 
2. Что такое static я знаю, и с самого начала никаких проблем с ним не было, и в коде все написано правильно.
3. Вы написали что то вроде *"Если правильно понял, то для каждого потока Вы будете делать свой экземпляр"*, и что иначе нужно будет синхронизировать потоки, я же сказал что (в примере подразумевается) для нескольких потоков один экземпляр, и что так как я ничего там не записываю, то все будет работать правильно ?!

Comment: Путем быстрого нагугливания, всплыло ключевое слово volatile, но вот [тут](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2006/04/volatile.html) говорится что нужно лочить на чтение мол может считаться не то что есть на самом деле, так вот вопрос, если (*теоретически*) в программе допускается например что один лишний раз выполнится кусок кода за **"if (ths->variable)"** когда variable уже на самом деле false, то он в самом деле просто выполнится или вылетит какая нибудь чудовищная ошибка порчи памяти ?

Comment: Про 1) понял, набросок, больше о том как лучще (на мой взгляд) писать не буду.

--

Про 2) ОК.

--

Про 3) После того, как Вы добавили ThHandle, стало очевидно, что правильно работать будет только с одним потоком. Для каждого потока, свой экземпляр WorksObject.

Прикиньте, Вы запускаете второй поток. Его HANDLE ThHandle замещает ThHandle предыдущего. В деструкторе сработает CloseHandle только для последнего потока.

Видимо Вы хотите, чтобы несколько потоков разделяли общий объект ?
Тогда в нем нужен, например, вектор их HANDLE. Вообще-то от общей логики задачи зависит.

Comment: @lirik90 volatile -- указание оптимизатору компилятора "не трогай эту переменную!"

Comment: главное не флудить в конструкторе класса))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcpy(td->qwerty, "Text");` - здесь должно быть нормально. ThreadData на этот момент уже сконструирован, все будет ок. Но если это с++, то почему не использовать `std::string` ?

`td->Obj = this;` вызвать то можно, но только нужно понимать, что на этот момент `WorksObject` ещё не сконструирован полностью. И если этот указатель использовать для других целей, то может быть плохо:) (другие методы и функции могут не знать, что объект ещё не полностью сконструирован...)

Вот чего нельзя делать в конструкторе (и в деструкторе также) - так это вызывать виртуальные методы. Можно почитать [здесь](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/08/joy-of-programming-calling-virtual-functions-from-constructors/).

Comment: Спасибо, но всетаки про указатель, В момент присваивания ему будет куда указывать, то есть если я потом я по этому указателю к памяти обращусь, все хорошо будет ???

Comment: должно быть ок. Если только кто то с другого треда указатель не потрет.

Comment: А если qwerty член WorksObject ???

Comment: вопрос не понятен.

Comment: В посте сверху код поправил, qwerty1

Comment: а почему там должна быть проблема?

Comment: нуу, qwerty1 член *недоконца* созданного класса :) Не ?!

Comment: не используйте чужие слова, если не понимаете сути. Класс не до конца сконструирован? это что то новое:)) не путайте объект и класс.

В Вашем коде WorksObject в конструкторе обращается к своему полю. Ему это сделать никто не мешает. Он то ведь знает состояние себя любимого:)

Answer (score 0):

[@lirik90](/users/7607/lirik90), у меня комментарии кончились. Поэтому последний переношу сюда. В ответ (?)

Про 1) понял, набросок, больше о том как лучше (на мой взгляд) писать не буду.

Про 2) ОК.

Про 3) После того, как Вы добавили ThHandle, стало очевидно, что правильно работать будет только с одним потоком. Для каждого потока, свой экземпляр WorksObject.

Прикиньте, Вы запускаете второй поток. Его HANDLE ThHandle замещает ThHandle предыдущего. В деструкторе сработает CloseHandle только для последнего потока.

Видимо Вы хотите, чтобы несколько потоков разделяли общий объект ? Тогда в нем нужен, например, вектор их HANDLE. Вообще-то от общей логики задачи зависит.

Про доступ к переменным по чтению. По сути надо лочить **критические секции**, а в них входят, обычно, по проверке переменных. Ну и вообще, где-то ведь ее меняют ? Иначе зачем проверять-то ? Поэтому лучше лочить.

Непосредственно по теме вопроса - *что нельзя делать в конструкторе ?*

Нельзя вызывать методы, которым нужен полностью сконструированый объект. Понятно, что при вызове конструктора память под все его поля уже отвели, а вот чем она заполнена ?
Например, у Вас td до new будет NULL и т.д.